# Change what is returned by the SingleOrDefault method

Tags: linq

Is it possible to change what is returned by the `SingleOrDefault` method?

Or will the default be always null?

Comment: No, but if the default is actually `null` it can easily be achieved by just a few more characters: `SingleOrDefault() ?? myDefault`. Or a bit longer, but still supplied by the framework: `Where(...).DefaultIfEmpty(...).SingleOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to change what is returned by the SingleOrDefault method in EF Core?

No.  "Default" in this context means "Null except for non-nullable value types, then the default value".  The terminology is borrowed from the [default operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default) in C#.

You can, of course, provide your own Extension Method that does whatever you want.  EG:

```
static class MyDefaultExtension
{
    public static T SingleOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> col, Func<T> defaultFactory)
    {
        using (var e = col.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (e.MoveNext())
            {
                var rv =  e.Current;
                if (e.MoveNext())
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains more than one element");
                }
                return rv;
            }
        }

        return defaultFactory();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can by preceding `.SingleOrDefault` with `.DefaultIfEmpty` extension method

```
var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
var result = numbers.Where(number => number > 10)
    .Select(number => $"Number: {number}")
    .DefaultIfEmpty("None")
    .SingleOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(result); // None
```

Because we explicitly providing default value we can use `Single` method instead of `SingleOrDefault`